# How to join the bones?

Tags: rigging, bones

[image: Trying to connect them (Offset)]

(I'm new AF I started this morning by watching tutorials and stuff but they are at 90% outdated)

So, a model I got from the internet misses the rig for the hand/fingers so they stay like that and doesn't do much else (apart from one being the wrist), which makes the hands seem dumb, I saw Darrin Lile video (4 years ago) where he rigs his character and at a point, he Shifts right click on the bones (hand and Pinky) and blender highlights the two, but for me it just doesnt work, it does some weird stuff and I tried connecting them but it doesn't work, so i'm searching how to connect them, but Offseted, or whatever it's called, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate objects. To join them you have to enter the [object mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/modes.html#object-modes) first. On the screenshot, the selected bone (and it's armature) is in *edit mode*. Press <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> to go into object mode or choose *Object Mode* from the footer menu of the 3D view.

When you are in object mode you should be able to select both of the armatures by <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> clicking. When both are selected (and highlighted) you can join them by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. All objects of the same type can be joined in object mode with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. Now you can enter edit mode again (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>) and select both bones.

Comment: I'll try right now and see, coming back to report!

Comment: So I chose both of the bones in Obj mode and it says that they're not meshes :\    https://imgur.com/iSomK85

Comment: and sorry for spamming, but in the video the guy chose the last bone of the arm and the first of the finger, but for me, it takes the whole armature of the arm and finger, normal?

Comment: You have to only (1) select the two armatures, you have selected additional objects in your screenshot. Try pressing A untill all is deselected the try preciscely selecting only the two armatures. [If they are hard to click on you will have to use the outliner.] After joining them and returning to edit mode, you will be able to select individual bones of this newly joined object.